# $y = \sin^{-1}x + (\sin^{-1}x)^2$, find the value of $\frac{d^{2r + 1}y}{dx^{2r + 1}}$ at x = 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: If $y = \sin^{-1}x + (\sin^{-1}x)^2$ show that the value of $\frac{d^{2r + 1}y}{dx^{2r + 1}}$ when x = 0 is $\frac{1}{2r}(\frac{(2r)!}{r!})^{2}$

I got $Dy = \frac{1 + 2\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

and I know that $D^{2r + 1}y$ is $D^{2r}(Dy)$ but I'm clueless as to how to move further from this point.

What am I supposed to do?

Please provide a solution if you have idea.

Comment: The formula is not true for $r=0$ since you divide by $0$, but $2*0+1=1$ gives the derivative

Comment: I think it should be $\left(\frac{(2r)!}{r!2^r}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\arcsin x$ is odd, $(\arcsin x)^2$ is even, so doesn't contribute to any odd-ordered derivative at $x=0$. As noted in a comment, I get$$\left.\frac{d^{2r+1}}{dx^{2r+1}}\arcsin x\right|_{x=0}=(2r+1)![x^{2r+1}]\arcsin x=\frac{(2r)!^2}{4^rr!^2}$$(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series)).

Answer (score 0):

Just treat the base case $r=1$ (you need to calculate the third derivative) and observe what terms you get (in particular, those with terms with $x$ will be canceled when you take $x=0$). Then proceed by induction (for general $x$) and use $D^{2(r+1)+1}y(x)=D^2D^{2r+1}y(x)$.